# Bootstrap tabs do not switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Unfortunately I cannot force my tabs to switch.

I've used the code once and it worked, I used the same versions of jQuery and Bootstrap.

I cannot find the conflict here. There are no identical ids in my code and as far as I can see my CSS does not overwrite the bootstrap CSS.

I use jQuery 2.1.4 and Bootstrap 3.3.4.

The code:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">
      Tutorial Point Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#ios" data-toggle="tab">iOS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#jmeter" data-toggle="tab">jmeter</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
      <p>tab1 text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ios">
      <p>tab2 text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="jmeter">
      <p>tab3 text</p>
   </div>

</div>
<script>
   $(function(){
      $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      // Get the name of active tab
      var activeTab = $(e.target).text(); 
      // Get the name of previous tab
      var previousTab = $(e.relatedTarget).text(); 
      $(".active-tab span").html(activeTab);
      $(".previous-tab span").html(previousTab);
   });
});
</script>
```

EDIT
I've found the code which is in conflict with the tabs, it's responsible for smooth scrolling:

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 700);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to make them both work? Can I change # for something else?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your javascript? If you remove it your tabs work. See example http://jsfiddle.net/3jmzryfp/

Comment: No, it still doesn't work :( I suppose maybe there is some conflict with my main nav?

Comment: You have messed up your code a lot, on the Solutions site.
please remove multiple versions of jquery there.
and try to use a stable jquery version and below it, simply add bootstrap.min.js
It should work fine, there is no need to write this above script tag.

Comment: I've found the code that doesn't work with the tabs.  Please take a look at my edit note.

Answer (score 0):

The `return false` in the animate function is causing the problem because it the never returns to allow the Bootstrap tab toggle to work. Change it to this..

```
$(function(){

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      // Get the name of active tab
      var activeTab = $(e.target).text(); 
      // Get the name of previous tab
      var previousTab = $(e.relatedTarget).text(); 
      $(".active-tab span").html(activeTab);
      $(".previous-tab span").html(previousTab);
   });

   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 700);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/R4VRTQcx46

Comment: thank you very much, now both things work but the scrolling function "jumps" at the beginning. http://solutionsmvo.nazwa.pl/tyszka/#kierowanie-budowami

Maybe just adding some code to scrolling function sayin that it should not react to href=ids in the tabs??